# Remove NonStrictExpectation which was defined previously

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I have this NonStrictExpectation in my JUnit test case:

```
  new NonStrictExpectations(mCurrencyDao) {
      {
        invoke(mCurrencyDao, "readSqlQuery", withAny(String.class));
        result = prepareTestSQL(pAllKeysForTest);
        times = 1;
      }
    };
  mCurrencyDao.loadAll(lToday);
```

which works pretty fine and leads to the expected result.
Now I had changed my code to this:

```
  new NonStrictExpectations(mCurrencyDao) {
      {
        invoke(mCurrencyDao, "readSqlQuery", withAny(String.class));
        result = prepareTestSQL(pAllKeysForTest);
        times = 1;
      }
    };
  mCurrencyDao.loadAll(lToday);
  mCurrencyDao.loadAll(lTomorrow);
```

the second call `mCurrencyDao.loadAll(lTomorrow);` has to be executed without my `NonStrictExpectations`.

Is there an easy way to remove my previous defined `NonStrictExpectations` after I called `mCurrencyDao.loadAll(lToday);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mockit.Invocation` class to invoke the original method that has been mocked by `Deencapsulation.invoke()`. The following code snippet delegates to original method on second method invocation.

```
new NonStrictExpectations(mCurrencyDao) {
    {
        invoke(mCurrencyDao, "readSqlQuery", withAny(String.class));
        result = new Delegate<String>() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String delegate(Invocation invocation) {
                if (invocation.getInvocationIndex() == 0) {
                    return prepareTestSQL(pAllKeysForTest);
                } else {
                    return invocation.proceed();
                }
            }
        };
        times = 2;
    }
};
mCurrencyDao.loadAll(lToday);
mCurrencyDao.loadAll(lTomorrow);
```